# Use a Web Service in C# Windows App

Tags: c#, web-services

I am new to using web services. I am assigned a task in which I need to use a web service in my Windows app. This is the web service I would be using:
https://api.betfair.com/global/v3/BFGlobalService.wsdl

Now, I've learned how to add a web reference to this service, but I could not find a basic tutorial that could help me learn how to make an object of this web service and use the service as I want to.

Basicaly, what I need is to create an object from the above web service in my form, and to call it's methods. A C# code snippet would be great.

Can anyone give me some directions? I am working in Visual Studio 2008 and a C# Windows App.

Comment: What exactly did you try and it didn't work? Please, make your question more specific and targeted - that way, your chances of getting some help will skyrocket.

Comment: @DavidBrabant: i did googled the topic many times, but it either shows how to create a web service to add two no., or it shows forum links which are kind of not very helpfull,

Comment: When I google `consume web service c# tutorial`, the second result is exactly what you need http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2761/Consuming-Web-Services-from-a-Win-Forms-Applicatio

Comment: @EricJ.: gosh i might have overlooked that page, it might b exactly what i need, thanxx a lot, i'll go through it right now =)

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore, This is many years back, I'm in a similar situation, and from your experiences since this question, would you be able to suggest a good book that covers webservices using C# primarily that involves SOAP, thanks in advance

Comment: A great example [here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-Consume-Web-Service-ASMX-in-Windows-Forms-WinForms-application-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. Right click on References
2. select Add Service Reference
3. give the wsdl address in the address textbox
4. click Discover
5. Give a name  for the namespace eg;- BFG
6. You can access the resources like BFG.MethodName() from you code

Comment: Perhaps - but how do you pass parameters to the webService?  This is really just half an answer.  I won't vote it down but could you elaborate on how to pass parameters?